# Return a JSON without keep the data in memory

Tags: python, json, django, http, memory

To give an example, let's assume this situation: I have in the database all the car models released from 1950 to today (so a lot of data).

In this case I speculated about cars, but it can be literally anything.

I want to create an HTTP API (with Python and Django, but the concept is valid for any framework) that returns the name and brand of all the cars I have saved (a JSON list).

Clearly querying the database and keeping all cars in memory, then serializing them to JSON is not an option (it would take too much memory).

So what's the best way to generate a JSON, from large amounts of data in the database, and then return it via HTTP?

Here is a code example to systematize the concept:

```
def get_cars_view(request):
    my_cars_json_stream = collect_json_without_keep_in_memory(Car.objects.all())
    return HttpResponse(my_cars_json_stream)
```

Comment: You can't. Response - is a single object. It has to be formed first and then sent via http, it can not be sent continuosly. Have you considered pagination?

Comment: @go2nirvana thanks, It's not a problem that I have, I was just curious to know how I can manage to collect lot of data without keep them in memory, for an HTTP response. Pagination can definitely be an option.

Comment: Have you looked into [`StreamingHttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse)? Example https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/outputting-csv/#streaming-large-csv-files

Comment: @Ralf that's interesting! This can be a viable alternative to a JSON response. Thank you